# variable in class not returning updated value

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm relatively new to actionscript 3, and this one has me stumped. Here's my class;

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Clicker extends MovieClip {

        public var clicks:uint;
        public var string:String;

        public function Clicker() {
            // constructor code
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, alignCentre);
            string = "clicks: ";
            clicks = 5; // I can change it here
        }
        public function clicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
                clicks++;
                trace(clicks); // it outputs updated value here
        }
        public function alignCentre(e:Event):void{
            x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - width/2;
            y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - height/2;
        }
        public function addedToStageHandler(e:Event):void{
            this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked);
        }
        public function get_clicks():uint{
            trace(clicks); // gives me whatever I initialise it to in the constructor
            return clicks;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to return the value of clicks from my Clicker class, but the value remains whatever I set it to in the constructor within get_clicks(), and I'm not sure why.

The variable has class scope, so why would it return the default value (in this case, 5) of clicks from get_clicks()? my clicked() method traces the correctly updated value. Is it a scope issue? I'm very confused.

This is my first frame where I create the object;

```
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

var clicks:TextField = new TextField();
var circle:Clicker = new Clicker();
clicks.text = circle.get_clicks().toString();
trace(circle.get_clicks());
addChild(circle);
addChild(clicks);
```

As you'd expect from the problem I'm having, trace spits out 5 over and over, and Clicks doesn't change from 5.

Edit:

There was a mistake, but fixing it has caused clicks not to update at all. I had a library version of the movieclip on my first frame rather than adding the object to the frame with addChild. Now that I've added circle, clicks does not update as my clicked() method isn't being triggered when I click my object.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. How how are you calling get_clicks() ?

Comment: @Karma: from an instance of the class on the first frame. I assign the method to a text field's text property (after converting it to a string). The value of clicks both inside get_clicks() and what is returned is 5. Yet, I click my Clicker object, and it outputs 6, then 7, then 8..get_clicks still reports 5.

Comment: You might wanna include that code too. That's probably where the error is.

Comment: @Karmer: I've added the code from my first frame where I call the class object.

Comment: Based on this code, all I see is that you instantiate a new Clicker with its clicks property set to 5. Then you set the Textfield to display that value. And then you trace out the value once. Where is the code that is causing it to trace 5 over and over?

Comment: I had an extra frame in my timeline by mistake. I think that was causing it. I think I've just misunderstood how the frame works. I want it to keep refreshing the screen with the updated value of clicks, which obviously it won't do as there's nothing there to loop. I'll add a listener to my frame for the action. However that's not really want I want. I want it to create the objects, then run the last 4 lines of code repeatedly. I think I need to use the timeline for that.

Comment: I've resolved it now. It was due to a misunderstanding in the behavior of frames.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

```
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

var clicks:TextField = new TextField();
var circle:Clicker = new Clicker();
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(100,0);

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void{
    trace("Timer is Triggered");
    trace(circle.get_clicks());
    clicks.text = circle.get_clicks().toString();

    addChild(circle);
    addChild(clicks);
}
myTimer.start();
```

Rather than use the timeline and frames, I wrapped the code I wanted to repeat in a timer listener. Works exactly as intended.

Comment: FYI you could move the addChild lines outside of the timer, so it doens't re-add the components each time the timer updates.

Comment: Ah, good point. They're already added to the stage. Thanks for the tip. :)